# How do I parse and validate command line arguments in Raku (formerly known as Perl 6)?

Tags: raku

In Perl 5, I can use `Getopt::Long` to parse commandline arguments with some validation (see below from http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

```
use Getopt::Long;
my $data   = "file.dat";
my $length = 24;
my $verbose;
GetOptions ("length=i" => \$length,    # numeric
            "file=s"   => \$data,      # string
            "verbose"  => \$verbose)   # flag
or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

say $length;
say $data;
say $verbose;
```

Here `=i` in `"length=i"` creates a numeric type constraint on the value associated with `--length` and `=s` in `"file=s"` creates a similar string type constraint.

How do I do something similar in Raku (née Perl 6)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Basics

That feature is built into Raku (formerly known as Perl 6). Here is the equivalent of your `Getopt::Long` code in Raku:

```perl6
sub MAIN ( Str  :$file    = "file.dat"
         , Num  :$length  = Num(24)
         , Bool :$verbose = False
         )
{
    $file.say;
    $length.say;
    $verbose.say;
}
```

`MAIN` is a special subroutine that automatically parses command line arguments based on its signature.

`Str` and `Num` provide string and numeric type constraints.

`Bool` makes `$verbose` a binary flag which is `False` if absent or if called as `--/verbose`. (The `/` in `--/foo` is [a common Unix command line syntax for setting an argument to `False`](https://design.perl6.org/S06.html#Declaring_a_MAIN_subroutine)).

`:` prepended to the variables in the subroutine signature makes them named (instead of positional) parameters.

Defaults are provided using `$variable =` followed by the default value.

### Aliases

If you want single character or other aliases, you can use the `:f(:$foo)` syntax.

```perl6
sub MAIN ( Str  :f(:$file)    = "file.dat"
         , Num  :l(:$length)  = Num(24)
         , Bool :v(:$verbose) = False
         )
{
    $file.say;
    $length.say;
    $verbose.say;
}
```

`:x(:$smth)` makes additional alias for `--smth` such as short alias `-x` in this example. Multiple aliases and fully-named is available too, here is an example: `:foo(:x(:bar(:y(:$baz))))` will get you `--foo`, `-x`, `--bar`, `-y` and `--baz` and if any of them will pass to `$baz`.

### Positional arguments (and example)

`MAIN` can also be used with positional arguments. For example, here is [Guess the number (from Rosetta Code)](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Guess_the_number/With_feedback_(player)#Perl_6). It defaults to a min of 0 and max of 100, but any min and max number could be entered. Using [`is copy`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Signature#Parameter_Traits_and_Modifiers) allows the parameter to be changed within the subroutine:

```perl6
#!/bin/env perl6
multi MAIN
#= Guessing game (defaults: min=0 and max=100)
{
    MAIN(0, 100)
}

multi MAIN ( $max )
#= Guessing game (min defaults to 0)
{
    MAIN(0, $max)
}

multi MAIN
#= Guessing game
( $min is copy #= minimum of range of numbers to guess
, $max is copy #= maximum of range of numbers to guess
)
{
    #swap min and max if min is lower
    if $min > $max { ($min, $max) = ($max, $min) }

    say "Think of a number between $min and $max and I'll guess it!";
    while $min <= $max {
        my $guess = (($max + $min)/2).floor;
        given lc prompt "My guess is $guess. Is your number higher, lower or equal (or quit)? (h/l/e/q)" {
            when /^e/ { say "I knew it!"; exit }
            when /^h/ { $min = $guess + 1      }
            when /^l/ { $max = $guess          }
            when /^q/ { say "quiting"; exit    }
            default   { say "WHAT!?!?!"        }
        }
    }
    say "How can your number be both higher and lower than $max?!?!?";
}
```

### Usage message

Also, if your command line arguments don't match a `MAIN` signature, you get a useful usage message, by default. Notice how subroutine and parameter comments starting with `#=` are smartly incorporated into this usage message:

```perl6
./guess --help
Usage:
  ./guess -- Guessing game (defaults: min=0 and max=100)
  ./guess <max> -- Guessing game (min defaults to 0)
  ./guess <min> <max> -- Guessing game

    <min>    minimum of range of numbers to guess
    <max>    maximum of range of numbers to guess
```

Here `--help` isn't a defined command line parameter, thus triggering this usage message.

### See also

See also the [2010](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/day-2-interacting-with-the-command-line-with-main-subs/), [2014](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/the-cool-subset-of-main/), and [2018](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2018/12/16/day-17-checking-your-list-twice/) Perl 6 advent calendar posts on `MAIN`, the post [Parsing command line arguments in Perl 6](http://perl6maven.com/parsing-command-line-arguments-perl6), and the [section of Synopsis 6 about MAIN](https://design.perl6.org/S06.html#Declaring_a_MAIN_subroutine).

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous editor who explained parameter aliases. Also thanks for introducing me to the idea of placing the commas before the 2nd, 3rd, etc parameters in the signature. I think that this can really help make signatures more tidy.

Comment: Can the variable's value, e.g. `$file` be assigned inside MAIN, but also carried outside of MAIN?

Comment: @con I assume you are referring to the `Getopt` technique of declaring your variables ahead of time and then populating them using `Getoptions`. I haven't tried that, because I find this technique cleaner. If I need the value of `$file` to be used elsewhere, I can use it as an argument to another subroutine (a.k.a. function). Please explain further, if I seem to be missing your point.

Comment: if you want to use the command line variables (e.g. `$file` or `$length`), you can only use them only inside `MAIN`? I have tried assigning them to variables outside `MAIN` but get errors.
`my $file = 'blah';

sub MAIN (Str :f(:$file)) {
   say "in MAIN $file";
}

say "outside MAIN \$file is $file";`

Comment: @con Correct. The `$file` inside the `MAIN` subroutine is scoped to that subroutine.

Comment: @con (Sorry about formatting). `perl6 example.p6 --file=foo` results in 
 
`outside MAIN $file is blah 
in MAIN foo`

Comment: @con I don't get errors when I run `perl6 example.p6 --file=foo` or `perl6 example.p6 -f=foo`. Perhaps you need an `=` sign. (Perl 6 currently requires an `=` sign for named parameters, even for the single letter options.)

Comment: Is there any way I could get the variables outside the scope of `MAIN`? Sometimes my scripts can be very long, I don't want to keep everything trapped in `MAIN`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171696/discussion-between-christopher-bottoms-and-con).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, there is a [Getopt::Long](https://modules.perl6.org/dist/Getopt::Long:cpan:LEONT) for perl6 too. Your program works in it with almost no modifications:

```
use Getopt::Long;
my $data   = "file.dat";
my $length = 24;
my $verbose;
get-options("length=i" => $length,    # numeric
            "file=s"   => $data,      # string
            "verbose"  => $verbose);  # flag

say $length;
say $data;
say $verbose;
```